# Implementing a dialog over a RecyclerView that goes over views but is located from a specific view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, view, popup, overlapping

I need to create the following UI -

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the requirements are that when I click on a day a popup will show with relevant information starting from the top of that days blue bar, and depending on the day of the week sometimes it will show in the right side and sometimes at the left side.

I tried to implement it as a RecyclerView where each ViewHolder has a bubble view at around 80% height at either side symmetrically with a default visibility of `GONE`, but the requirements are that the bubble View goes over previous / next elements in the list (as shown in both pictures), so I can't use this approach as the bubble will make the ViewHolder expand itself until the bubble ends if I use `wrap_content` or it will just be cut somewhere in the middle if I use a fixed side.

I though about a "naive solution" to implement this view without using a RecyclerView - the fact that the days of the week are a set number which won't change is something I can use in my favor. In order to do so, I can copy and paste the code that I used to build the ViewHolder the fixed amount of days in the week - 7 times - to the relevant Fragments layout and put them inside a ScrollView for making sure small devices can see it all. This approach which will allow me to implement the required overlapping as they are all in the same view so I can apply `elevation` into each bubble, but it is a really bad practice that I wish not to use because I copy and paste a lot of code and I make my XML huge.

Here is the XML of my ViewHolder called `viewholder_weekly_progress` -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <com.tistory.zladnrms.roundablelayout.RoundableLayout
        android:id="@+id/weekly_progress_activity"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:backgroundColor="@color/blue"
        app:cornerLeftTop="60dp"
        app:cornerRightTop="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.daasuu.bl.BubbleLayout
        android:id="@+id/bubblelayout_weekly_progress_steps_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-4dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:bl_arrowDirection="right"
        app:bl_arrowHeight="8dp"
        app:bl_arrowPosition="16dp"
        app:bl_arrowWidth="8dp"
        app:bl_bubbleColor="@color/lightBlue"
        app:bl_cornersRadius="26dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/weekly_progress_activity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/weekly_progress_activity"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/weekly_progress_activity"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.200">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            tools:text="5000/4000 steps " />

    </com.daasuu.bl.BubbleLayout>

    <com.daasuu.bl.BubbleLayout
        android:id="@+id/bubblelayout_weekly_progress_steps_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:bl_arrowDirection="left"
        android:layout_marginStart="-4dp"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:bl_arrowHeight="8dp"
        app:bl_arrowPosition="16dp"
        app:bl_arrowWidth="8dp"
        app:bl_bubbleColor="@color/lightBlue"
        app:bl_cornersRadius="26dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bubblelayout_weekly_progress_steps_left"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/weekly_progress_activity"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bubblelayout_weekly_progress_steps_left">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            tools:text="5000/4000 steps " />

    </com.daasuu.bl.BubbleLayout>


    <com.tistory.zladnrms.roundablelayout.RoundableLayout
        android:id="@+id/weekly_progress_goal"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:backgroundColor="@color/green"
        app:cornerLeftTop="60dp"
        app:cornerRightTop="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/weekly_progress_activity"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/weekly_progress_activity" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weekly_progress_day_name"
        style="@style/H2_Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/weekly_progress_goal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/weekly_progress_activity"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weekly_progress_activity"
        tools:text="Sun" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/weekly_progress_current_day_indicator"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/weekly_progress_day_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/weekly_progress_day_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weekly_progress_day_name"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am using 2 libraries for creating the bars and the bubbles, both can be found in the following links -

https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/BubbleLayout

https://github.com/zladnrms/RoundableLayout

I am interested in XML solution - if you got a Compose solution that will also be okay, but I will need the XML equivalent.

Thanks

Comment: You can use some tooltip library for generating tooltip that is similar to your required popup

Comment: Thank you. But how would that tooltip be positioned relatively to each viewholders blue bar?